# What prevents adding the 64-bit Windows platform to VCL component packages?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, target-platform

With most Delphi and C++ Builder projects, including component packages, you can add a 64-bit Windows target by right-clicking on the Target Platforms item in the Project Manager and selecting Add Platform, then choosing '64-bit Windows' in the resulting dialog.

Recently while installing components in a new installation of RAD Studio XE4, I've been unable to do this for some components.  For example:

[image: The Add Platform dialog with only OSX and 32-bit Windows showing]

This specific example is [TMS's Advanced Poly List](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advpolylist.asp), but it's happened for other component packages as well - but not all.  Some have the target available, and for those I can build the package and create a 64-bit VCL forms application that uses the component fine.

**What is preventing the Win64 target appearing in the dialog, and how can I re-enable it?**

Comment: Is it a designtime package? Did you install 64 bit compiler?

Comment: The 64-bit compiler is installed and works for other packages.  This specific package is both designtime and runtime (ack) but I believe I have seen it with runtime-only packages where the component library had both designtime and runtime packages.

Comment: Changing this package to 'runtime only' does not add the Win64 target back into the dialog.

Comment: Closer inspection shows this package is a C++ Builder package, referencing a single .cpp file as well as the Pascal files.  If I make a new C++ package myself, I can only target Win32 and OSX.  If I make a Delphi package, I can also target Win64 (as well as iOS etc.) Yet the 64-bit C++ compiler is installed and I can compile and run a 64-bit VCL C++ application.

Comment: ...and it appears that [in XE3, 64-bit packages aren't supported](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/C%2B%2BBuilder_64-bit_Windows_Differences#Producing_64-bit_Packages_Not_Supported) and so presumably this hasn't been done in XE4 yet either.  Crikey.  Talk about hiding an important missing feature in a one-line note deep in the documentation :/

Comment: You can answer your own question now.

Comment: I guess so, yes :/  It'll take a few minutes - I'm entering a QC report (there is none about this issue!)

Comment: I think that is about binary compatibility. Delphi x64 is built upon Visual C++ OBJ/LIB files format (rumours were it even included some parts of VC++ backend for x64). However BCB x64 is based on LLVM + CLang and their intermediate binaries mostly follow UNIX ELF convention. I think those 64-bit intermediate files are just  incompatible. You can have pure-Delphi project or pure-BCB but you cannot directly fuse them into one.

Comment: @Arioch'The: the QC report is linked in my answer, just posted. I'll be curious why too. I'm not sure what difference the object file format would make since once linked into an EXE or BPL, the 'format' of the resulting file is the same afaik... but perhaps some of the metadata that is built into a BPL can't currently be carried through?

Comment: To compile it BCB should read intermediate files from Delphi ad vice versa. Before there is BPL and EXE - there are DCP/DCU/OBJ/LIB/BPI - and whatever LLVM adds to the list. Even in pure Delphi You cannot compile EXE against BPL without DCP (or sources to recreate DCP). Same holds for LLMV+dcc64 hybrid - they have to have common intermediate language, that they don't have.

Comment: @Arioch'The, what rumours were these? Do you have a link?

Comment: @David M no. it was before XE3 release when EULA bomb was unleashed. That was discussed in a number of blog and someone "Delphi Insider" (or maybe someones) posted details time to time. On some blogs his posts were deleted by EMBA request, other posts survived. All those posts were anonymous of course, but they sounded reasonably so they *could*  contain real fact. Whether they did or not - no one outside EMBA can know for sure. Google can easily sow you posts like http://delphihaters.blogspot.ru/2012/09/a-compiler-guy-leaves.html but again that has no sources for rumours

Comment: Component projects can still not chose 64bit in C++ Builder XE5...

Comment: @MaxKielland Not good.  I hope they add it soon! One alternative might be to build the project and link the object files in directly, effectively the same as statically linking the BPL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++ Builder XE6, released a few days ago (mid-April 2014), you can now [create 64-bit packages in C++](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/rad-studio/whats-new?cid=701G0000000tP05).

---

Old **outdated** answer (valid for C++ Builder XE3, 4 and 5):

64-bit compilation is a [missing feature for C++ packages in XE3 and XE4.](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/C++Builder_64-bit_Windows_Differences#Producing_64-bit_Packages_Not_Supported)

For Delphi, you can target Win32, Win64, OSX and (I think) iOS for packages.

For C++, you can only target Win32 and OSX, even if you have the 64-bit compiler installed.  This is documented for XE3, and is apparently not fixed in XE4 either.

There was no QC report for this, so [I have added one](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=117238).  Please feel free to vote for it.  My rationale for its importance is that packages are an important part of the Delphi / VCL ecosystem, especially for components.  While you can use Delphi-created 64-bit packages in your 64-bit C++ project, this means **you can't use components written in C++ in a 64-bit program.**  For us, this will require rewriting our components in Delphi, or waiting until the compiler supports it.

Comment: they posted an answer to you: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=116564 ==> http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/C%2B%2BBuilder_64-bit_Windows_Differences#Producing_64-bit_Packages_Not_Supported